# How to set foreground color of progress bar programatically?

Tags: c#, progress-bar, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to change the foreground color of a progress bar dynaically in code but the usual assignment for setting the color isn't working for a progress bar.

This is how I'm trying to set the foreground color:

```
ProgressBar.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
```

But the error I'm getting is:

> an object reference is required for the nonstatic field method or
>   property,'system.windows.controls.control.foreground.get'

This is the XAML declaration of the progress bar:

```
<ProgressBar  IsIndeterminate="False" x:Name="workProgressBar" Maximum="100" Foreground="BlueViolet" Margin="59,185,55,295" FontWeight="Bold" Style="{StaticResource ProgressBarStyle3}"/>
```

Does anyone know how to set the foreground color programmatically?

Comment: Sounds like `ProgressBar` is not a `static` class and that's why callind `Foreground` method requires a reference of a `ProgressBar` class. Try with `ProgressBar p = new ProgressBar(); p.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);`

Comment: Sounds like your ProgressBar isn't called ProgressBar - perhaps you could include the XAML that defines it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ProgressBar is the name of the class, rather than the name of your instance.  Assuming that your progress bar has the name myProgressBar, the below should achieve what you want.

```
myProgressBar.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
```